# Map dynamic/generic properties with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a scenario where I have a propertybag of key/values that would look something like:

```
Entry 1 : key="Load", value="2", type="int"
Entry 2 : key="DailyStatus", value="0", type="bool"
```

I am trying to figure out if it's possible with nhibernate to map these values to a single table that I can pull out at a later time into .net simple types.

I am trying to avoid creating classes to contain all of this data as it can be very repetitive and doesn't allow portions of the application to be as flexible as possible. I had considered storing it in XML or JSON, but this data has to be queried against on a pretty regular basis.

Has anyone mapped dictionaries of simple types to a table in nhibernate and pulled the data back out? I suppose mapping to a generic dictionary would work:

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<object, Type>>
```

I can do it by hand, but if there is a builtin way for nhibernate to accomplish it that would be easier.

Comment: Are the set of Type s you want to store defined at runtime or are they all defined at compile time? Are they limited to the .net primitive types (ie the IConvertible) or are others possible? And which database are you using? (I suspect what you want to do might be possible depending on the answers to these questions, but it is a non-trivial solution and hence why I ask first)

Comment: They are all known ahead of time at compile time. At the current moment they all would be able to use iconvertible, although this may change but I'm assuming at this point they are all .net simple types. Mostly bool and ints

Comment: Forgot databases: MsSql2005. Possibly 2008, but at this point we're assuming it's going to be 2005. On this note it shouldnt really matter as we're using nhibernate. Forgot to mention we're also using the nhibernate linq extensions

Comment: Yes, most of the time underlying database isn't relevant. Sqlite however allows you to set any type of primitive to a single column, which probably would have been quite useful for you. I'm still a little confused about exactly what you want. Initially I thought you just want to store (string, IConvertible, Type) tuples (or maybe even just (string, IConvertible), as you can get the Type from the IConvertible?), but the nested Dictionary confuses me a little.

Comment: the nested dictionary was incorrect in my original question. you are correct I think IConvertible and a simple class to encapsulate these would be sufficient. IDictionary<string, Entry>. Where entry:

public class Entry
   Type Type
   object Value

I believe that would work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you create a class "Triplet" with attriutes id, key, value, type and then map it to a table called whatever you want?

Comment: that would work, but how can I tell nhibernate what the underlying type of the records are? When I access the dictionary items I want to get the simple type. Maybe using generics?

I suppose this would require casting to the type value

Comment: You mean what you have in the "type" attribute of the Triplet class. Maybe you could map a Triplet class to a private field and then have a  generic dictionary as public. You would populate this dictionary from the private field, using some kind of factory, or maybe just switch statement on the "type" attribute of the Tripplet. You would have to keep track of the changes so that you can push/pull entries to a private field. I am doing something simmilar, except I am serializing the whole object graph into a private field.